# Fiddler Script - SaveResponseBody()

Tags: fiddler

I want to save all png images that are loaded along with some webpage into a separate folder.
I am using below code with in Fiddler Script [CustomRules.js].

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session)
{
if(oSession.url.EndsWith(".png"))    
{
oSession.SaveResponseBody();
}
//Actual content of  OnBeforeResponse function.
}
```

Problem here is, I was unable to find any image got saved within Program files/Documents.

Where do “SaveResponseBody()” will save the HTTP Response Body?

Can we give our own custom folder?

My Fiddler version is (v4.4.5.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `SaveResponseBody()` method saves the files to your `\Documents\Fiddler2\Captures\` folder. If you want to use a different name, use the overload that accepts a filename. You should check the Response's status code is 200 to ensure that you're not trying to save off HTTP/304 responses which won't contain a body. Also, rather than looking at the URL, you probably want to check the response's type.

So you end up with something like this:

```
if ((oSession.responseCode == 200) && 
   oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/png")) 
{ 
  SaveResponseBody("C:\\temp\\" + oSession.SuggestedFilename);
}
```

Note: The manual way of doing this would be to go to the QuickExec box below the Web Sessions list, type `select png` and hit Enter, then click File > Export > Selected Sessions > Raw Files.

Comment: Thanks Eric, it is working for me. Is there any way to save the images that are greater than certain size? [So that i can skip the icons etc]

Comment: Sometimes, I'm seeing error (Windows alert) as - Save Failed - Could not find a part of the path 'D:\temp\'. How to fix this?

Comment: Use `oSession.responseBodyBytes.Length` as a criteria to limit export to images of a certain size. To address the missing path issue, ensure that `D:\temp\` exists.

Comment: Path 'D:\temp' really exists and there are few images in that folder that are actually saved by the same fiddler script itself. So even with folder existence we are seeing the error.