# Fiddler script to automatically save response body

Tags: scripting, fiddler

I need help writing a script for fiddler. What I need is to automatically save a certain response body every time it comes up in the session window.

I have tried to follow the instructions in this post [Fiddler Script - SaveResponseBody()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179711/fiddler-script-saveresponsebody) but I just get an error when I try and save CustomRules.js. (I could be inserting in wrong or in the wrong place)

I am new to fiddler and scripts so any help here would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried adding this:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
   if(oSession.url.EndsWith(".png")) {
      oSession.SaveResponseBody(); //Actual content of OnBeforeResponse function.
   }
}
```

and then adding this:

```
if ((oSession.responseCode == 200) &&
    oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/png")) {
   SaveResponseBody("C:\\temp\\" + oSession.SuggestedFilename);
}
```

to the CustomRules.js script.

Comment: Please post what you've tried already?

Comment: I have tried adding this "static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session)
{
if(oSession.url.EndsWith(".png"))                          
{
oSession.SaveResponseBody();
}
//Actual content of  OnBeforeResponse function.
}"                                                                       and then adding this                                               "if ((oSession.responseCode == 200) && 
   oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "image/png")) 
{ 
  SaveResponseBody("C:\\temp\\" + oSession.SuggestedFilename);
}" to the CustomRules.js script

Comment: What exactly is the "error" you get when you save the script?

Comment: Variable 'SaveResponseBody' has not been declared. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 7):

SaveResponseBody is a method on the oSession object.

```
oSession.SaveResponseBody("C:\\temp\\" + oSession.SuggestedFilename);
```

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to add your code within **OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) { ... }** function

The following code will save the request and response body of any url that contains "procedimentoservice" and a response code that differs from OK (200).

```
if (oSession.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains("procedimentoservice"))
        {
            if(oSession.responseCode != 200)
            {
                var directory2 = "C:\\log\\NEXT\\";
                var filename2 = oSession.oRequest.headers['SOAPAction'].ToString().Replace('"','') + "_" + Guid.NewGuid();
                var path2: String = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory2, filename2);

                oSession.SaveRequestBody(path2 + "_request.txt");
                oSession.SaveResponseBody(path2 + "_response.txt");
            }
        }
```

File names will be in the following format:

```
c:\log\NEXT\CriarEvento_fa15709e-b2a8-402d-a623-e4f01e6e8ae1_request.txt
c:\log\NEXT\CriarEvento_fa15709e-b2a8-402d-a623-e4f01e6e8ae1_response.txt
c:\log\NEXT\CriarEvento_ff650cf8-8fe6-47a2-8552-a4d8bce246f3_request.txt
c:\log\NEXT\CriarEvento_ff650cf8-8fe6-47a2-8552-a4d8bce246f3_response.txt
```